# strptime and I18n, how to parse a date for current language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, localization, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using `strptime` to parse a date formatted in `dd/mm/YYYY` format, however I just thought that simply parsing in this way will break i18n support, because if my customer is using a different language I will try to parse it in my format, while I want it to use `date.formats.default` format in that function.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved my problem in this way:

```
Date.strptime(params[:date], I18n.translate('date.formats.default'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Date or Time you can use .to_s to apply default format

```
Date.today.to_s
Time.now.to_s
```

Comment: This doesn't allow me to read a date using the same date format I use when I do `Date.today.to_s`